# VB.NET, MySQL and Unicode

Tags: mysql, vb.net, unicode, utf-8

How to input the textbox's unicode string to MySQL database. I changed utf8 charset the MySQL Database. I'm using VB.NET 2005 and MySQL Database for Window application. Please Help me.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Post some code and explain how you'd like to improve the behaviour

Answer (score 4):

You simply add

```
Character Set=utf8;
```

inside your connection string.
 Example:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=db;Uid=user;Pwd=pwd;Character Set=utf8;"
```

Answer (score 1):

`CharacterSet=UTF8;` worked for me. (`Character Set=UTF8;` not worked) driver MySQL Connector NET 6.5.4

Answer (score 0):

try this method.. it work for me

```
Public ConnString As String = "Server=localhost; 
    Database=shiftd;
    Uid=root;
    Pwd=;
    Character Set=utf8;"
```